# HTML <select> tag and HttpPost Java

Tags: java, android, html, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to load some HTML from a webpage using HTTPPost and Java. The way the webpage works, there is a dropdown menu that the user uses to select between different students. What I want to do is change students using that dropdown.

[image]

The HTML for the dropdown on the website:

```
<select name="_ctl0:ddlStudents" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;_ctl0$ddlStudents\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" language="javascript" id="_ctl0_ddlStudents">
    <option selected="selected" value="2096730">Patil, Neil Sanjay</option>
    <option value="2109090">Patil, Yash Sanjay</option>

</select>
               <noscript>
                  <input type="submit" name="_ctl0:btnSwitchStudent" value="OK" id="_ctl0_btnSwitchStudent" /></noscript>
```

I'm trying to use HTTPpost to push the second element of the dropdown as selected like this:

```
HttpPost httppost;
HttpResponse response;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_ctl0_ddlStudents", "2109090"));
url = new URI("https://gradespeed.austinisd.org/pc/");
                httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

But it just loads the page like the first element of the dropdown has been selected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but for the first element in the dropdown you have selected="selected". This is what makes it selected

Comment: Yes. What I am trying to do is have the second dropdown be selected when I load the page again.

Comment: Http POST sends the user selections of a form to the server, it does not (necessarily) change the values that are on the screen